# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 - Removing ppas not possible

Tags: updates, ppa, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Upgrade fails, telling me

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This was likely caused by: 
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu  Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge  package to remove software from a
>   Launchpad PPA and  try the upgrade again.

Removing all ppas with

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xx/yy
```

Does not have an effect.

When I open `Software & Updates`,  I cannot remove anyting in the `other Software` tab, since the `remove` button is greyed out.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Is `sudo ppa-purge ppa:xx/yy` exactly what you write? And what are the exact output?

Comment: sudo ppa-purge ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: This is when I repeat the ppa-purge ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak, I did not store the output when it succeeded

Answer (score 2):

As before you upgrade Ubuntu ,you have to remove unnecessary and corrupted packages . I have resolved issue by following commands:

```
apt list --upgradable
sudo apt autoremove
sudo do-release-upgrade -h
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot of solutions, but the following solution worked for me:

To check for the **ppa** files, do:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then check for each **ppa** file there, then do:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:<ppa_name>
```

Follow this and you can be able to upgrade your system.